# UnboundLocalError when fitting neural network - TensorFlow bug?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

Consider the following "hello world" of neural networks:

```
(X_train, y_train),(X_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
X_train, X_test = X_train / 255.0, X_test / 255.0


net = keras.models.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Flatten(),
  keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

net.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

net.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, verbose=True)
```

**Calling the fit method leads to the exception below.**

Versions:

```
keras: 2.2.4
tensorflow: 1.13.1
```

I installed keras and tensorflow freshly with Anaconda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras tensorflow
```

The following warnings seem suspicious, but a solution is not clear:

On module import:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
/Users/cls/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.6 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.7
  return f(*args, **kwds)
```

On compile:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/cls/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
```

Somewhere in stdout:

```
2019-05-14 16:40:10.628107: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
```

**Error message**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed eval> in <module>

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    951             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
    953         # Prepare validation data.
    954         do_validation = False

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    675             # to match the value shapes.
    676             if not self.inputs:
--> 677                 self._set_inputs(x)
    678 
    679         if y is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _set_inputs(self, inputs, outputs, training)
    587                 assert len(inputs) == 1
    588                 inputs = inputs[0]
--> 589             self.build(input_shape=(None,) + inputs.shape[1:])
    590             return
    591 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in build(self, input_shape)
    219             self.inputs = [x]
    220             for layer in self._layers:
--> 221                 x = layer(x)
    222             self.outputs = [x]
    223             self._build_input_shape = input_shape

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    455             # Actually call the layer,
    456             # collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 457             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    458             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    459 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py in call(self, inputs, training)
    124                                  seed=self.seed)
    125             return K.in_train_phase(dropped_inputs, inputs,
--> 126                                     training=training)
    127         return inputs
    128 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in in_train_phase(x, alt, training)
   3103     """
   3104     if training is None:
-> 3105         training = learning_phase()
   3106         uses_learning_phase = True
   3107     else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in learning_phase()
    133         phase = tf.placeholder_with_default(False,
    134                                             shape=(),
--> 135                                             name='keras_learning_phase')
    136         _GRAPH_LEARNING_PHASES[graph] = phase
    137     return _GRAPH_LEARNING_PHASES[graph]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in placeholder_with_default(input, shape, name)
   2091     A `Tensor`. Has the same type as `input`.
   2092   """
-> 2093   return gen_array_ops.placeholder_with_default(input, shape, name)
   2094 
   2095 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in placeholder_with_default(input, shape, name)
   5923   shape = _execute.make_shape(shape, "shape")
   5924   _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
-> 5925         "PlaceholderWithDefault", input=input, shape=shape, name=name)
   5926   _result = _op.outputs[:]
   5927   _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    509                 dtype=dtype,
    510                 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 511                 preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    512           except TypeError as err:
    513             if dtype is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx, accept_symbolic_tensors)
   1173 
   1174     if ret is None:
-> 1175       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1176 
   1177     if ret is NotImplemented:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    302                                          as_ref=False):
    303   _ = as_ref
--> 304   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    305 
    306 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    243   """
    244   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 245                         allow_broadcast=True)
    246 
    247 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    281       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
    282           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape,
--> 283           allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    284   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    285   const_tensor = g.create_op(

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    571     raise TypeError(
    572         "Element type not supported in TensorProto: %s" % numpy_dtype.name)
--> 573   append_fn(tensor_proto, proto_values)
    574 
    575   return tensor_proto

tensorflow/python/framework/fast_tensor_util.pyx in tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util.AppendBoolArrayToTensorProto()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py in asscalar(***failed resolving arguments***)
    545     warnings.warn('np.asscalar(a) is deprecated since NumPy v1.16, use '
    546                   'a.item() instead', DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=1)
--> 547     return a.item()
    548 
    549 #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You can safely ignore the AVX warning, it wont cause any errors. Seems that your conda installed tensorflow version that does not match your python version and it would be a good start to fix that. Try running "pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow" (or "tensorflow-gpu", depending on your environment) and see if error reproduces

Comment: Seems like a good place to start. However, I am trying not to mix conda and pip when managing packages. Can this be done with conda? And how is it possible that anaconda has installed the wrong tensorflow?

Comment: I am no expert on conda. Yet, the recommended way of installing tensorflow is pip. Conda creates their packages themselfs and therefore not as invested in getting things right.

Comment: And the error is gone: Install tensorflow with pip, not with conda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Tensorflow 1.14 the official package distribution supports python 3.4 and over. Not sure if there is a sepparate wheel for each version of python, but the good idea would be to install tensorflow the recommended way though `pip install`.

The command to try to fix the issue:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow
# pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu
```

**Update:** Tensorflow 1.13 does not support python 3.7

Comment: It doesn't?

`Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'1.13.1'`